# How to put only Mondays on xticks in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.dates import MO, WeekdayLocator

sns.lineplot(x="datum", y="people", data=data_s, hue="expedice")
plt.ylabel("People")
plt.xlabel("Datum")

loc = WeekdayLocator(byweekday=MO, interval=1)

plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.legend(loc = 'upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

which gives me this output:

[image]

But I would like to display only every Monday on xticks, because now it is not legible at all. How can I do this please?

Comment: @BigBen see my edit, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the locator gets created but is never actually applied, and also the x ticks look like they might be strings instead of datetimes, so:

1. Make sure the dates have been converted [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)
2. Apply the [`WeekdayLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.WeekdayLocator) using [`set_major_locator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_locator.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.dates import MO, WeekdayLocator

#1 convert to datetime
data_s["datum"] = pd.to_datetime(data_s["datum"])

ax = sns.lineplot(x="datum", y="people", data=data_s, hue="expedice")

#2 apply weekday locator
loc = WeekdayLocator(byweekday=MO, interval=1)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
```