# Mark Only Mondays in X Axis of Graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following code that produces the graph below. Everything is great but I want to change the X axis so the tick marks fall on every Monday. So for example, I would still want the 10/1/21 data in the graph but the first tick, would read '2021-10-04' (Monday) instead of '2021-10-01'.

I would also want it every Monday, not every other Monday.

```
Board_Table = pd.pivot_table(ED_Daily, values='BED_ORDERED_TO_DISPO_HOUR', index=['Date'],
                   columns=['ADM_LOCATION'], aggfunc=np.sum)
Board_Table = pd.DataFrame(Board_Table.to_records())
Board_Table = Board_Table.fillna(0)

plt.plot( 'Date', 'Acute', data=Board_Table, marker='o', color='green', linewidth=2)
plt.plot( 'Date', 'ICU', data=Board_Table, marker='o', color='red', linewidth=2)
plt.plot( 'Date', 'Psych', data=Board_Table, marker='o', color='blue', linewidth=2)
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70957673/how-to-put-only-mondays-on-xticks-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

This code did the trick:

```
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 6), dpi=80)
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    lines = ax1.plot( 'Date', 'Acute', data=Board_Table, marker='o', color='green', linewidth=2)
    lines = ax1.plot( 'Date', 'ICU', data=Board_Table, marker='o', color='red', linewidth=2)
    lines = ax1.plot( 'Date', 'Psych', data=Board_Table, marker='o', color='blue', linewidth=2)
    loc = WeekdayLocator(byweekday=MO, interval=1)
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
    ax1=plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
    ax1=plt.legend()
    ax1=plt.xlabel('Day')
    ax1=plt.ylabel('Total Boarding Minutes')
    ax1=plt.title('Total Boarding Minutes Of Patients Bed Order to Dispo 240m+'+ DateRange)
    ax1=plt.savefig("Total Boarding Minutes Of Patients Bed Order to Dispo 240m+" + DateRange + ".png", format="png")
    #ax1=plt.close()
```